# angular.copy() not copying the array and selection sort not working

Tags: arrays, angularjs, copy

I am new to AngularJs and working on an AngularJs project. I have had an issue with one of the code segments and would like to request your help with that.

I have a problem where `$scope.arrayEvent` is not copied to `$scope.arrayReminder`. In the console log, I see the following.

[image]

The task is about setting a reminder.

```
$scope.sortedArrayEvent = function(){
   $scope.sortedArrayEvent = function(){
   // console.log('$scope.arrayEvent: '+$scope.arrayEvent);
   // $scope.arrayReminder  = angular.copy($scope.arrayEvent);

    $scope.arrayReminder =[{reminderName:"green",reminderTime:"06:00:00",reminderDate:"19/04/2020"},
                           {reminderName:"yellow",reminderTime:"07:00:00",reminderDate:"20/04/2020"},
                           {reminderName:"blue",reminderTime:"08:00:00",reminderDate:"18/04/2020"}];
    let index = $scope.arrayReminder.length;
    for(let i =0;i<index-1;i++){
        let minIndex =i;
        for (let j = i+1; j<index; j++){
            if ($scope.arrayReminder[j].reminderDate < $scope.arrayReminder[minIndex].reminderDate){
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }
        let temp = $scope.arrayReminder[minIndex];
        $scope.arrayReminder[minIndex] = $scope.arrayReminder[i];
        $scope.arrayReminder[i] = temp;

        $scope.sortedArray = [{sortedEventName:$scope.arrayReminder[2].reminderName,
            sortedEventTime:$scope.arrayReminder[2].reminderTime,
            sortedEventDate:$scope.arrayReminder[2].reminderDate,
        }]
    }
}
```

Then I tried hardcoding the array with 3 objects. I want to have the latest `reminderDate` (`{reminderName:"yellow",reminderTime:"07:00:00",reminderDate:"20/04/2020"}`) together with its `reminderName` and `reminderTime`. But I get something else.

Can someone help me fix this?
After this hard-coding issue is fixed, my ultimate goal is to fix the `angular.copy()` issue. That is what is needed. Please help

Comment: `... But I get something else.` - can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you need deep cloning  but the `angular.copy` creates a new object/list.

In your case `$scope.arrayReminder  = angular.copy($scope.arrayEvent);`

**If you do any manipulation** with `$scope.arrayEvent`, the  `$scope.arrayReminder` **will stay the same**.